# How to use UItabbar on a UIviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

currently I have a main Viewcontroller. Now I wish to implement the UItabbar to switch between few controllers. The problem now is this main view controller is just a normal UIviewcontroller, how can I implement the UItabbar and switch vc with selecting the tabbar item? Thanks all

Comment: Do you mean, you have viewController and inside you have TabBar? Or your app has TabBar?

Comment: @DavidKadlcek currently my app dont have any tabbar. So with current design I need to implement a tabbar, so i found it very hard because the hierarchy is very complicated. So what should I do to implement tabbar?

Comment: Add a tabBarcontroller to storyboard , Drag to give a connection between tabbarcontroller to uiviewcontroller (relationship Segue "viewcontroller")

Answer (score 0):

if you are using storyboard 
Get uitabbarcontroller-and link between it and the viewcontroller(by right click and drag to the view controller then select view controller from the drop menu)

Here is a tutorial 
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=nGx3MZM460c

Comment: the problem is the main vc is already inherit from UIviewcontroller, how to make it behave like an UItabbarcontroller?

Comment: you can instead inherit it from `UITabBarController`.  instead of using `myVC:UIViewController`, use `myVC: UITabBarController`. BTW i use tab bars using story board. if you can implement Tab bars using storyboard, i can help

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz I wish to dont change the UIviewcontroller to UItabbarcontroller, so what should I do in storyboard?

Comment: just drag a UITabBarController. you will get two default view controllers[tabs] with it. Remove them. and instead use your own view controllers. `Control drag` from your desired controller to `tab bar controller` and selected `Relationship segue -> Root view Controller` .

[helpful video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFw1yVhG4r8)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create TabBar into your project you have to write it into AppDelegate:

```
let nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController()) // ViewController inside TabBar
nav1.tabBarItem.title = "Title of VC"
nav1.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "name_of_image")
let tabBarVC = UITabBarController()
tabBarVC.viewControllers = [nav1] // All VCs, what you want in TabBar
window?.rootViewController = tabBarVC
```

So I hope it helps you. If you write code programmatically without the storyboard.

Comment: bro what if i create the Tabbar on storyboard? what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

through storyboard you can add tabBarcontroller to menuviewcontroller
intially my storyboard is like this
[image]

Drag from tabbarcontroller to menuviewcontroller you will get a pop up like this

[image]

Select relationship Segue "viewcontroller" and your storyboard will look like this

[image]

Comment: hi, I follow your way, but the tab bar is not showing, the behaviour is so weird

Comment: set tabBar as intial controller

Comment: still failed bro

Comment: can a swift project have more than 1 initial controller?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its been made simpler since these answers were written.  But it seems quite straightforward now - at least with Xcode 11.5.

So to add a tab bar to an existing Storyboard that's already got a UIViewController:

1. Drop a 'container view' onto your existing view.  Pin it to the safe area.  It doesn't need to cover the whole thing - eg. if you want a non-tabbed bit at the top.  But it makes sense for it to extend it down to the bottom of the view - otherwise your tabs end up looking very non-standard!
2. When you dropped the container view, that will have created a new UIViewController for the container's contents.  Delete it.
3. Now drop a Tab Bar Controller on the storyboard - eg. next to the main view controller's view.  This creates three new view controllers - the tab bar controller, plus one for each of the two tab items it creates by default.

Now the crucial bit - we want to make the container view contain the tabbed views...

- Select the Tab Bar Controller, select the Connections inspector, and drag from the 'Embed' presenting segue to the container on your main view.
- Once you've dragged, a menu will pop up by the cursor with a single item - 'viewDidLoad'.  Make sure you select this.  It can be a bit fiddly to do for some reason - but once you select it correctly you'll see the link from 'Embed' to 'Container View viewDidLoad' in the Tab View Controller's connections inspector.

Voila! - you're done!